# Please help me fix the grammar in a birthday letter 祝你生日快乐!!! 对不起, 让你久等了

Tags: grammar, writing-critique

Where do I need to fix grammar? I know for a fact something must be wrong...

> 于一文:
>
> 你好!
> 祝你生日快乐!!! 对不起, 让你久等了。祝你年年有今日，岁岁有今朝。祝万事如意。谢谢你的万事。有机会的话，大家见个面。
>
> 他不但是我的老师还是我的哥哥。
> 我爱你♡

Comment: No effort shown, downvote

Comment: He wrote the text by translating English into Chinese as best as he could. Although not perfect, I would say he did enough.

Answer (score 3):

> *于一文: 你好!*

If 于一文 is your friend, you should just use the first name 一文, and write: "**一文, 你好**!"

If you like to keep English favor in your letter, you can add 'dear' like in English letter and write: "**亲爱的一文, 你好**!"

> *祝你生日快乐!!! 对不起, 让你久等了。*

If you need to apologize for lateness, better put it in first, and write  "**对不起, 让你久等了, 祝你生日快乐!!!**"

> *祝你年年有今日，岁岁有今朝。*

This phrase is kind of dated, and only suitable for blessing a person in advanced age or at least in late middle age. If you must use it, put it in a separate paragraph to emphasize your blessing

> *祝万事如意。*

No problem with this phrase

> 谢谢你的万事。

It is an attempt to translate "thanks for everything" but we don't use 万事 this way (the correct usage is another topic). The literal translation is "一切都多得你" ; However, "thanks for everything" imply "thanks for everything you have done for me" which shouldn't be omitted in Chinese, so the correct translation is "**谢谢你为我所做的一切**"

> *有机会的话，*

It sounds like you and this person rarely have chance to meet. If it is not the case, you should add "next time" and write: "**下次有机会的话**，"

> *大家见个面。*

It sounds too blunt, I suggest "**(希望)大家(能再)见面。**"

> *他不但是我的老师还是我的哥哥。*

Do you mean: "**你不但是我的老师, 也是我的哥哥。**"?

> 我爱你♡

Chinese don't use to say "I love you" but you are not Chinese, so it is ok.

Here is my edition:

> 亲爱的一文, 你好!
>
> 对不起, 让你久等了, 祝你生日快乐, 万事如意!!!
>
> 谢谢你为我所做的一切! 下次有机会的话， 希望大家能再见面。
>
> 你不但是我的老师, 也是我的哥哥。
>
> 我爱你♡

Note 1:

In Chinese, we only use 万事 at the beginning of a phrase. It acts like an exclamation.

Example:

"万事有我" (I would deal with everything!)

"万事都有例外" (There's exception in everything!)

Note 2:

*见个面 (meet once) --> 能再见面 (can see each other again)*

zyy wrote:

> *I would say 兄长 is better than 哥哥。*

Consider replacing '哥哥' with '兄长' and write: "你不但是我的老师, 也是我的兄长" if you want to be more formal.

However, using '哥哥' is also acceptable, and it shows more passion-- consider the next phrase is "我爱你"

Comment: I would say *兄长* is better than *哥哥*。

Comment: '兄长'  is better if the letter is written in a formal manner,  but using '哥哥' show more passion-- consider the next phrase is "我爱你"

Comment: I know I'm not the one asking this question but thank you for your explanation. I can learn from your answer too ^___^